# Why doesn't mangohud work with wine?

Tags: wine, games, winetricks, vulkan

I can't get mangohud to work on games I run through wine

This the command I used:

```
mangohud wine <.exe_file>
```

I have also tried:

```
mangohud --dlsym wine deadcells
```

This is the output it throws at me:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libMangoHud_dlsym.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libMangoHud.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libMangoHud_dlsym.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libMangoHud.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk wine-staging 6.12 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0074:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0074:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

006c:fixme:seh:virtual_unwind calling personality routine in system library not supported yet
006c:fixme:seh:virtual_unwind calling personality routine in system library not supported yet
006c:fixme:seh:virtual_unwind calling personality routine in system library not supported yet
006c:fixme:seh:virtual_unwind calling personality routine in system library not supported yet
006c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
006c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Unknown error (998).
006c:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
0094:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0094:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:err:environ:run_wineboot boot event wait timed out
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f0:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
^C0104:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 7BC69360 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0104, blocked by 0024, retrying (60 sec)
00f8:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 000000007BC6B540 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 00f8, blocked by 0034, retrying (60 sec)
0100:err:sync:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 000000007BC6B540 "dlls/ntdll/loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0100, blocked by 002c, retrying (60 sec)
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a 32bit game?
Have you tried installing 32bit mangohud?

Comment: Is it running on Lutris or Steam?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that was exactly the problem.

```
sudo pacman -S lib32-mangohud
```

In Ubuntu there must be a package for this and perhaps it is the one with the same name.

**Updated for Ubuntu:**

Looking at the MangoHUD documentation, it's best to install it like this:

```
sudo apt install mangohud mangohud:i386
```

Comment: To install the 32-bit version, the following pattern namePackage:i386 is used.
So to install mangohud 32 bits, use the command:

`sudo apt install mangohud mangohud:i386`